Proof by Induction: $k$-concavity in sets of $2^k$ points
I am having problems completing the following proof by induction. Any help would be welcomed.
Problem Statement:
We define a $k$-concavity as a set of $k+1$ points in the plane such that the slopes formed by joining all the points consecutively form a strictly increasing or decreasing sequence.
Claim: Every point in a set of $2^k$ points in general position (there are not any three colinear points) belongs to some $k$-concavity.
Proposed Proof (by induction):
Base Case:
For $k=1$, we have $2^1 = 2$ points. These two points trivially form a 1-concavity.
Inductive Hypothesis:
We assume that the claim is true for $k = n$, i.e., in any set of $2^n$ points, every point belongs to an $n$-concavity.
Inductive Step:
Consider a set of $2^{n+1}$ points. We divide it into two subsets $A$ and $B$, each with $2^n$ points.
By the inductive hypothesis, each point in $A$ belongs to an $n$-concavity formed by points of $A$, and each point in $B$ belongs to an $n$-concavity formed by points of $B$.
At this point, I do not know how to conclude the proof.
Thanks in advance for your help!
EDIT
I have a possible conclusion of the proof, but it is needed a Lemma, that seems true / provable but I do not know how to prove. Can anyone confirm if (i) the Lemma is provable, or provide a proof, and (ii) if with the Lemma, we can complete the proof of the Claim?
Here is the conclusion, starting from where I did not know how to finish:
To complete the proof, we need the following lemma:
Lemma: If every point in some set $S$ belongs to an $n$-concavity, then adding any additional point $P$ guarantees that $P$ will form at least one $(n+1)$-concavity with some points in $S$.
Arguments towards a proof:
On the contrary, suppose $P$ does not form any $n+1$-concavity with points of $S$. By the inductive hypothesis, picking $2^n - 1$ points of $S$ together with $P$ guarantees that $P$ belongs to at least some $n$-concavity with some of those picked points. There are $2^n$ different subsets formed with $2^n - 1$ points of $S$ and $P$ for which $P$ belongs to at least some $n$-concavity. Also, we could let "out" of the picked points every time a point of the $n$-concavity to which $P$ belongs, assuring that every new $n$-concavity differs from the previous one at least in one point. Therefore, $P$ belongs to at least $2^n - n$ $n$-concavities which are different in at least one point.
Despite this arguments, I have not been able to produce a formal proof of this Lemma. Any help would be welcomed!
Returning to the inductive step: By the Lemma, each point in $B$ will form an $(n+1)$-concavity with points in $A$, and each point in $A$ will form an $(n+1)$-concavity with points in $B$. Therefore, every point in $A \cup B$ belongs to an $(n+1)$-concavity. This completes the inductive step.
Therefore, by induction, the claim holds for all $k \geq 1$.

In the definition of $k$-concavity, when you say that we join the points of the set consecutively, I guess we enumerate the points form the first to the $k+1$th and then join the first point with the second, the second with the third, and so forth up to the $k$th point which we join with the $k+1$th point, right?

It seems that the conclusion in your arguments fails because when we let "out" too many points there will remain to few points to apply the inductive hypothesis.

@AlexRavsky yes, a $k$-concavity is a concatenation of $k+1$ points in a single path with $k$ slopes that are monotonically increasing or decreasing with respect some reference frame

@AlexRavsky on your second comment, we only let out one point each time, so we always have a set of $2^k$ points: point $P$ and $2^k-1$ points belonging to set $S$. But if the "left out" point belongs to the previous $n$-concavity, we have that the $n$-concavity to which $P$ belongs by the inductive hypothesis is different from the previous one (at least in one point, the one "left out")

But I guess this new $n$-concavity can coincide with some $n$-concavities before the previous, so in general we can fail to have $2^n−n$ distinct $n$-concavities containing $P$.

I'm not sure I understand the problem correctly but if I do the claim is not true.
A counter example is the set of $2^k-1$ of coordinates $(a,2^a)$ for $a$ ranging from 1 to $2^k-1$ plus the point $P=(2^k,0)$.
$P$ is not part of any k-concavity.

As far as I see, the sequence $(P,(1,2^1),\dots, (2^k-1, 2^{2^k-1}))$ provides a concavity, because the first slope is negative and the next slopes are positive and increasing. Maybe we need to ask OP to clarify the notion of slope.

@AlexRavsky I have analyzed the counterexample and is valid for $k \geq 3$, as $P$ forms at most a $2$-concavity with points of $S$.

@wece thanks for the counterexample! Do you think that the Claim could be true if we stated that "For $i\geq 1$, if there is no $k+i$-concavity in a set of $2^k$ points in general position, then every point of the set belongs to some $k$-concavity"?

I agree wit @AlexRavsky. What you call concavity is a bit strange, we usualy see the sequence given by alex as concave.

Do you mean that the claim is now: $\forall$ set $S$ with $2^n$ points in general posistion, if $\forall i \geq 1$ there is no $k+i$-concavity then every point of $S$ is in a $n$-concavity?,

($\forall i\ge 1$ there is no $k+i$-concavity) iff there is no $k+1$-concavity.

@wece yes, that would be the claim

Maybe I should change the definition and use a more precise term. I was trying to define a convex polygon without one side. How would you denominate that? Just as plainly as I have done now?

@AlexRavsky well noted, it would suffice for the new claim to state if there is no $k+1$-concavity

@JuanMoreno Then an $m$-concavity is exactly a set of vertices of a convex $m+1$-gon. Therefore your question is very similar to the famous Erdős–Szekeres conjecture, but with the difference that each point is required to be a vertex of a convex $k+1$-gon.

@AlexRavsky you are right! Indeed, it seems that Erdös-Szekeres conjecture would follow from the modified claim, right?
